# Passing GET parameter with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a link that I want to use with ajax. Here is the link:

```
<a class="export_csv" href="ajax/createCSV.php?saleid=4"><img src="/img/record.csv.png"></a>
```

The ajax works fine but I can't pass through the GET variable. Here is the jquery:

```
$('.export_csv').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();    
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax/createCVS.php',
        type: 'GET',
        data: $(e).data['saleid'],   
        success: function(results){
            console.log('it worked');
        }
    });
});
```

Here is the target php page:

```
<?php
    include('./includes/global.php');

    //$cl = new Client();
    //$cl->createCSV();
    echo "This Works ";
    $test = $_GET['saleid'];
    echo $test;
    echo "did work for me";
?>
```

Comment: What is `$(e).data['saleid']`

Comment: You have to change `$(e).data['saleid']` to `{saleid: '<?=$_GET['saleid']=?>'}`

Answer (score 0):

`$('#myDomSelectorId').data['saleid']` need to be JSON formated like this :

`data : { saleid : $('#myDomSelectorId').data['saleid'] }`

Or directly `data : "saleid="+$('#myDomSelectorId').data['saleid']`

Full example :

```
$('.export_csv').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();    
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax/createCVS.php',
        type: 'GET',
        data: { saleid : $('#myDomSelectorId').data['saleid'] },   
        success: function(results){
            console.log('it worked');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: `e` in the context is an Event object. So it can't used as DOM element

Answer (score 0):

try like this ,send data to php page using data option
 $('.export_csv').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax/createCVS.php',
            type: 'GET',
            data: "saleid=4",
            success: function(results){
                console.log('it worked');
            }
        });

```
})
```

or

```
 $('.export_csv').on('click', function(e){
     urls=$(this).attr('href');
        e.preventDefault();    
        $.ajax({
            url:urls,
            type: 'GET',                  
            success: function(results){
                console.log('it worked');
            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the data as JSON format like

```
data:{saleid:$(e).data['saleid']}
```

But actually dont know what is `$(e).data['saleid']`